# Geojson data format output properly in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, geojson

i m trying to implement a service that displays data in geojson format.
I hit my database with this :

```
sql =
  "select ST_AsGeoJSON(boundaries)
  from cluster_shapes
  where category = '#{params[:category]}'
  and area_id =
  (select id 
  from areas
  where name = '#{params[:city]}' )"

connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
@clusters = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @clusters }
end
```

And I get ugly results that is not [valid geojson](http://geojsonlint.com/)

```
[
{
st_asgeojson: "{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[23.819537,38.039409],[23.81892,38.04068],...}"
,
st_asgeojson: "{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[23.919537,38.039409],[22.81892,38.04068],...}"
,
...
```

If I remove the ugly part **st_asgeojson** and make it look like this , it is valid geojson.

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[23.819537,38.039409],[23.81892,38.04068],[23.820912,38.040237],[23.8209752169298,38.0400047630785],[23.8209519774174,38.0399755885062],[23.8205266,38.0394558],[23.819537,38.039409]]]}
```

So the question is how do i **get rid** of "**st_asgeojson**"  ,or am i doing it wrong ?
PS:A model exist, if query is modified the result is pretty the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is simply nested inside your @clusters json, so you can simply parse it out...

instead of:

`format.json { render json: @clusters }`

you should change it to

`format.json { render json: @clusters[0].st_asgeojson }`

Or if you are expecting more than one result to be returned from you sql query, try

`format.json { render json: @clusters.map {|x| x.st_asgeojson }}`